# Encog normalize a new array ,consistent with previous treatment

Tags: java

I want to use Encog to train a Neural Network.Before it ,I normalize input dataset use the following code,The dataset has some nominal columns and it will be encoded.

```
    File newFile = new File(somewhere);
    EncogAnalyst analyst=new EncogAnalyst();
    AnalystWizard wizard=new AnalystWizard(analyst);
    wizard.wizard(file,true, AnalystFileFormat.DECPNT_COMMA);

    AnalystNormalizeCSV norm=new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
    norm.analyze(file,true, CSVFormat.ENGLISH,analyst);
    norm.setProduceOutputHeaders(true);
    norm.normalize(newFile);
    analyst.save(new File(somewhere));
```

Now I have a new array,and I want to normalize it use the same way as before dataset ,I know NormalizeArray can normalize array ,but the output seems not consistent with previous dataset because it has only one row,so the code of nominal columns is different. How can I normalize the new array correctly ? Thanks a lot.

```
    double array[] = {-0.99851,-0.998981,0,2009,-1,4,-1,-1,-1,1,-0.992481,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-0.992481,0};
    NormalizeArray norm = new NormalizeArray();
    norm.setNormalizedHigh(1);
    norm.setNormalizedLow(-1);
```